# Whats wrong with this TSR?

Tags: assembly, tsr

it should display the time but does nothing

```
;  PROGRAM FOR TSR FOR CLOCK

.MODEL TINY

.CODE

ORG 100H
START:

         JMP INITS            ;Jump to initialization portion
         ADRS DD ?

TIME1:
         PUSH AX
         PUSH BX
         PUSH CX
         PUSH DX              ;Save registers
         PUSH SI
         PUSH DI
         PUSH DS
         PUSH SS
         PUSH ES
         PUSHF

         MOV AX,0B900H
         MOV ES,AX            ;Load VRAM address
         MOV DI,820

         MOV AH,02            ;Get current time
         INT 1AH

         MOV AL,CH
         SHR AL,04            ;Hours in CH

         ADD AL,30H
         MOV ES:[DI],AL
         ADD DI,02

         MOV AL,CH
         AND AL,0FH
         ADD AL,30H
         MOV ES:[DI],AL
         ADD DI,02

         MOV AL,':'
         MOV ES:[DI],AL
         ADD DI,02

         MOV AL,CL            ;Minutes in CL
         SHR AL,04
         ADD AL,30H
         MOV ES:[DI],AL
         ADD DI,02

         MOV AL,CL
         AND AL,0FH
         ADD AL,30H
         MOV ES:[DI],AL
         ADD DI,02

         MOV AL,':'
         MOV ES:[DI],AL
         ADD DI,02

         MOV AL,DH            ;Seconds in DH
         SHR AL,04H
         ADD AL,30H
         MOV ES:[DI],AL
         ADD DI,02

         MOV AL,DH
         AND AL,0FH
         ADD AL,30H
         MOV ES:[DI],AL
         ADD DI,02

EXIT:
         POPF
         POP ES
         POP SS
         POP DS
         POP DI               ;Restore the registers
         POP SI
         POP DX
         POP CX
         POP BX
         POP AX
         JMP DWORD PTR CS:ADRS  ;Jump to restore original address of
                                ;Interrupt in IVT

INITS:
         MOV AL,00H           ;Clear screen
         MOV AH,06H
         MOV BH,07H
         MOV CX,0000H
         MOV DX,1832H
         INT 10H

         CLI                 

         PUSH CS
         POP DS

         MOV AH,35H           ;Get interrupt address of int 08h
         MOV AL,08
         INT 21H
         MOV WORD PTR ADRS,BX
         MOV WORD PTR ADRS+2,ES

         MOV AH,25H           ;Set new address of int 08 h
         MOV AL,08
         LEA DX,TIME1
         INT 21H

         MOV AH,31H           ;Request stay resident
         LEA DX,INITS         ;Load the no. of paragraphs of resident portion
         STI                  ;Restore interrupts
         INT 21H
END START
```

Comment: What OS do you use? Real MS-DOS (maybe in a virtual machine) or some MS-DOS emulator? Also note that you should not overwrite interrupt 0x08 but 0x1C. Did you already check if the interrupt is invoked at all? Note that the DX register for function 31h for interrupt 0x21 contains the number of paragraphs, not the number of bytes!

Answer (score 0):

Your program probably works but the output is displayed past the video ram!!!
I suppose you're using a standard text screen with 80 columns and 25 rows.
The VRAM starts at 0B800h and occupies 4000 bytes.

Did you mean to clear a window of 50 columns by 25 rows ? Your comment suggests you clear the screen.

Furthermore I suggest you don't `push ss` nor `pop ss`. They are simply not needed.

Why not consider using `pusha` and `popa` instead of all those separate instructions?

To correctly terminate and stay resident use :

```
lea dx,INITS
add dx,15
shr dx,4
```